# In Framing Frame, will the guards get alerted if they see a missing painting?

Tags: payday-2

In this heist, it's possible to steal the paintings without killing all the guards.  But if one of them see any missing painting, will he trigger the alarm ?

Comment: From experience, I do not believe so, we've frequently liberated the first room or two of paintings without the guards alerting but that could just be the path they took around the room - 3ventic is testing it for you right now though!

Comment: Oh, excellent.  We had the exact same experience, and we're wondering the exact same thing. Thanks a lot, looking forward to your answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the guards will not get alerted from a missing painting.

[image: Empty frame next to a guard]

Comment: So perfect that I got both the guard and the camera looking at the missing painting in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: on a side note, a guard WILL get alerted if he crosses some packed painting lying on the floor.

Comment: @Anto indeed they will, and same with cameras.

Answer (score 3):

While the guards will not be alerted if they don't see the painting where it belongs.

I highly recommend to be careful when moving the paintings because the cameras can be alerted to them.

Guards will be alerted if they see the painting on the floor.

Example: One time I threw a painting in the camera's range and it alerted everyone.

Mission Items in general are never detected to be missing when you take them otherwise day 3 for framing frames would require you to take out all the guards first.